# <input type="checkbox" /> why the slash in meteor.js guide?

Tags: meteor

There's a foward slash after type "checkbox" in meteor official guide using es2015 which I'd like to know the context of. This is meant to be a reactive client data input trigger, but I can't help wonder if this is as much about es2015 or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of a forward slash is a shorthand way of closing out the tag. It's equivalent in this case to the following:

```
<input type="checkbox"></input>
```